# How to count multiple string value in a same column with sum values in adjacent column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count, sum

I have the values "Sunday" "Saturday" "Holiday" "Leave" "Paid Leave" in a same column named as "Leaves". However i have the column named "WorkedDays" need the sum of worked days from the table.

```
$sqls = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT EmployeeNoA, 
                                    EmployeeNameA, 
                                    SUM(AttenInDays), 
                                    COUNT(Leaves=='Sunday'), 
                                    COUNT(Leaves=='Saturday'), 
                                    COUNT(Leaves=='Holiday'), 
                                    COUNT(Leaves=='Leave'), 
                                    COUNT(Leaves=='Paid Leave') 
                            FROM attend 
                            WHERE (SignInDate BETWEEN '$StartDate' AND '$EndDate') 
                            GROUP BY EmployeeNoA, EmployeeNameA");
```

I need the output as,

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Emp No.  | Emp. Name | sum(Worked Days) | count (Saturday)|count (Sunday)|count (Holiday)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
xxx001   |xxx        |    20            |     4           |     4        |  2          
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
xxx002   |yyy        |    22            |     4           |     4        |  0          
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
xxx003   |zzz        |    21            |     4           |     4        |  1          
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

These count (Saturday), count (Sunday), count (Holiday) are form single column with the string values Saturday, Sunday, Holiday, Leave, Paid Leave, Sick Leave, etc.... I need the count of separate string with sum of working days (it is integer in the table)

I am new to php. So please advise **what is the syntax i need to use these types of query**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of checking a value inside an aggregate clause is to return a value if it is true. Normally the value is 1 and then you SUM them up to provide a count.

This is a bit clearer if the IF statement is explicitly coded to return 1 or 0.

```
SELECT EmployeeNoA, 
        EmployeeNameA, 
        SUM(AttenInDays), 
        SUM(IF(Leaves='Sunday', 1, 0)), 
        SUM(IF(Leaves=Leaves='Saturday', 1, 0)), 
        SUM(IF(Leaves=Leaves='Holiday', 1, 0)), 
        SUM(IF(Leaves=Leaves='Leave', 1, 0)), 
        SUM(IF(Leaves=Leaves='Paid Leave', 1, 0)) ,
        SUM(WorkedDays)
FROM attend 
WHERE (SignInDate BETWEEN '$StartDate' AND '$EndDate') 
GROUP BY EmployeeNoA, EmployeeNameA
```

However this can be abbreviated to just a simple compare which evaluates to 1 or 0:-

```
SELECT EmployeeNoA, 
        EmployeeNameA, 
        SUM(AttenInDays), 
        SUM(Leaves='Sunday'), 
        SUM(Leaves='Saturday'), 
        SUM(Leaves='Holiday'), 
        SUM(Leaves='Leave'), 
        SUM(Leaves='Paid Leave') ,
        SUM(WorkedDays)
FROM attend 
WHERE (SignInDate BETWEEN '$StartDate' AND '$EndDate') 
GROUP BY EmployeeNoA, EmployeeNameA
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `SUM()` instead of `COUNT()` as `col = value` (also note that there's just one `=`) returns `true` or `false`, `1` or `0`.

```
SELECT 
  EmployeeNoA, 
  EmployeeNameA, 
  SUM(AttenInDays), 
  SUM(Leaves='Sunday'), 
  SUM(Leaves='Saturday'), 
  SUM(Leaves='Holiday'), 
  SUM(Leaves='Leave'), 
  SUM(Leaves='Paid Leave') 
FROM attend 
WHERE (SignInDate BETWEEN '$StartDate' AND '$EndDate') 
GROUP BY EmployeeNoA, EmployeeNameA
```